# java benchmarking : More time for lesser input

Tags: java, regex, performance, nutch

After running some benchmarking on 2 regex library implementations, below is the results that we got:

```
inputs   automaton      regex
 50      343ms          210ms
100      48ms           187ms
200      65ms           363ms
400      100ms          692ms
800      165ms         1385ms
```

Why the first run (with 50 inputs) is super expensive for both implementations ?

FYI: `automation` refers to http://www.brics.dk/automaton and 
'regex' refers to the java regex library.

Comment: Are the times reported for a single run? Or they are average of a number of runs. I think to have a more reliable result, it's better to report on average time for a number of runs (say 100 runs).

Comment: @SinaIravanian those were not average timings but for multiple runs i could see close-by values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the standard micro-benchmark issues with Java.

**JVM warmup**: Due to several parameters, the code is first often slow and becomes faster and faster when the execution time grows until it goes to steady-state.

**Class loading**: The first time you launch a benchmark, all the used classes must be loaded, increasing the execution time.

**Just In Time Compiler**: When the JVM identify a hot part of the code

**Garbage Collector**: A garbage collection can happen during the benchmark and with that the time can increase a lot.

One good [read](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-benchmark1/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, the regex is compiled. So the first run uses extra time. Also, there is probably a run-time optimization going on.